# i have problems query dsl jpa entity transform dto to map

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

noted: i'm sorry. i'm not english speaker, so i use translator.

i use spring boot & spring data jpa & querydsl

i have 2 entity and 2 dtos for api service

let me show you entity and dto first

```
//package and imports...

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long eventId;
    private String requestBy;
    private String content;
    private String difficulty;
    private String partyType;
    private LocalDate eventDate;
    private LocalTime eventTime;
    private String comment;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();

    private Event(Event.Builder builder) {
        this.requestBy = builder.requestBy;
        this.content = builder.content;
        this.difficulty = builder.difficulty;
        this.partyType = builder.partyType;
        this.eventDate = builder.eventDate;
        this.eventTime = builder.eventTime;
        this.comment = builder.comment;
    }

    public void addMember(Member member) {
        this.members.add(member);
        member.joinEvent(this);
    }

    public void addAllMember(Member... members) {
        Arrays.stream(members).forEach(this::addMember);
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Builder {
        //... something builder codes
    }
}
```

```
//package and imports...

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Event event;

    private String name;
    private String position;

    public Member(String name, String position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
    }

    void joinEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

}
```

```
//package and imports...

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EventDto {

    private Long eventId;
    private String requestBy;
    private String content;
    private String difficulty;
    private String partyType;
    private LocalDate eventDate;
    private LocalTime eventTime;
    private String comment;
    private List<MemberDto> members = new ArrayList<>();

    @QueryProjection
    public EventDto(Long eventId, String requestBy, String content, String difficulty, String partyType, LocalDate eventDate, LocalTime eventTime, String comment, List<MemberDto> members) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.requestBy = requestBy;
        this.content = content;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.partyType = partyType;
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.members = members;
    }

    public static EventDto convertEventToDto(Event event) {
        EventDto dto = new EventDto();

        dto.setEventId(event.getEventId());
        dto.setRequestBy(event.getRequestBy());
        dto.setContent(event.getContent());
        dto.setDifficulty(event.getDifficulty());
        dto.setPartyType(event.getPartyType());
        dto.setEventDate(event.getEventDate());
        dto.setEventTime(event.getEventTime());
        dto.setComment(event.getComment());
        event.getMembers().stream()
                .map(member -> new MemberDto(member.getId(), member.getName(), member.getPosition()))
                .forEach(memberDto -> dto.members.add(memberDto));

        return dto;
    }
}
```

```
//package and imports...

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MemberDto {

    private Long memberId;
    private String name;
    private String position;

    @QueryProjection
    public MemberDto(Long memberId, String name, String position) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

very simple entity and dtos.
event have members / each member have one event. one to many / many to one
there is no problems with the general queries.

so i try querydsl transform and it failed

i want transform to Map<Localdate(EventDto::eventDate), List>
so i made query below

```
public Map<LocalDate, List<EventDto>> findAllDtoByEventDateBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    Map<LocalDate, List<EventDto>> transform = queryFactory
            .from(event)
            .join(event.members, member)
            .where(event.eventDate.between(start, end))
            .transform(
                    groupBy(event.eventDate).as(
                            list(new QEventDto(
                                    event.eventId,
                                    event.requestBy,
                                    event.content,
                                    event.difficulty,
                                    event.partyType,
                                    event.eventDate,
                                    event.eventTime,
                                    event.comment,
                                    list(
                                            new QMemberDto(
                                                    member.id.as("memberId"),
                                                    member.name.as("name"),
                                                    member.position.as("position")
                                            )
                                    )
                            ))
                    )
            );

    return transform;
}
```

that code throws `IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

so i changed it to use Projections

```
public Map<LocalDate, List<EventDto>> findAllDtoByEventDateBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    Map<LocalDate, List<EventDto>> transform = queryFactory
            .from(event)
            .join(event.members, member)
            .where(event.eventDate.between(start, end))
            .transform(
                    groupBy(event.eventDate).as(
                            list(Projections.fields(
                                    EventDto.class,
                                    event.eventId,
                                    event.requestBy,
                                    event.content,
                                    event.difficulty,
                                    event.partyType,
                                    event.eventDate,
                                    event.eventTime,
                                    event.comment,
                                    list(
                                            Projections.fields(
                                                    MemberDto.class,
                                                    member.id.as("memberId"),
                                                    member.name.as("name"),
                                                    member.position.as("position")
                                            )
                                    )
                            ))
                    )
            );

    return transform;
}
```

it throws `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unsupported expression new MemberDto(member1.id as memberId, member1.name as name, member1.position as position); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported expression new MemberDto(member1.id as memberId, member1.name as name, member1.position as position)`

if i use groupBy().list() instead of groupBy().as(list()) it work make list perfectly but i want make Map without use other loop or stream outside

can i make Map use only QueryDsl? or have to use other logic?

thanks to read my question. sorry once again my english is bad.

Comment: add problem : and i write list(MemberDto).as("members") it throw ```org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Can not set java.util.List field com.momc.momc.model.dto.EventDto.members to java.lang.Long; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.List field com.momc.momc.model.dto.EventDto.members to java.lang.Long```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querdysl factory expressions (Projections) cannot be used together with group expressions. For advanced DTO projections with JPA, look for example at Blaze-Persistence Entity Views (also has a Querydsl integration).